# Security configuration in multiple jars

Tags: spring-security

I want to ask if it's possible to have my security configuration spread in multiple jars. For instance I have my project (myproj.war) that defines all the security rules in a @Configuration, but I also have my rest @Configuration in a separate jar(rest.jar) so people can put it in their classpath and immediately have the /rest/* support. 
This all works good until the point I want to add security to the rest configuration. I add the @Configuration with the @EnableWebSecurity in my rest.jar but it doesn't get picked up! I have a breakpoint in my DigestAuthenticationFilter and it never goes through it!!! However I can see that the bean is being created during startup the filter itself is never triggered!

**EDIT:**
Here's my war's Security web configuration:

```
@Order(value = 0)
public class StorefrontWebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webCtx.register(StorefrontSecurityConfig.class);
    webCtx.register(StorefrontMVCConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionMutexListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(webCtx));
    servletContext.addListener(new BroadcasterCreator());

    /* JAWR */
    .... jawr definitions ....

    /* Spring Delegating Dispatcher Servlet */
    final Servlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(webCtx);
    final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServletReg = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcherServlet", dispatcherServlet);
    dispatcherServletReg.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcherServletReg.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");
    dispatcherServletReg.addMapping("/");

    /* Character Encoding Filter */
    final FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("characterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForServletNames(null, false, dispatcherServletReg.getName());

    /* Resources Filter */
    final FilterRegistration resourcesFilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("resourceFilter", ResourceFilter.class);
    resourcesFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/resources/*");
    resourcesFilterReg.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/webjars/*");

    /* Storefront Delegating Filter */
    final FilterRegistration storefrontFilterChainReg = servletContext.addFilter("storefrontFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    storefrontFilterChainReg.addMappingForServletNames(null, false, dispatcherServletReg.getName());

    /* HiddenHttpMethodFilter Filter */
    final FilterRegistration hiddenHttpMethodFilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("hiddenHttpMethodFilter", HiddenHttpMethodFilter.class);
    hiddenHttpMethodFilterReg.addMappingForServletNames(null, false, dispatcherServletReg.getName());

    /* Spring Security Delegating Filter */
    final FilterRegistration springSecurityFilterChainReg = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    springSecurityFilterChainReg.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.<DispatcherType>of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC), false, dispatcherServletReg.getName());
    }
}
```

also the security configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class StorefrontSecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private ObjectPostProcessor<Object> opp;

@Resource
public ApplicationContext context;

// @formatter:off

@Order(1)
@Configuration
public static class CheckoutStorefrontSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    public ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .antMatcher("/checkout/**")
            .anonymous().principal("anonymous").authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS").and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()).and()
            .authorizeRequests().and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/checkout*").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/checkout/**").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/checkout/j_spring_security_check").requiresSecure().and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/checkout/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .loginPage("/checkout/login")
                .failureHandler(defaultCheckoutAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(defaultLoginCheckoutGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler((SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler) context.getBean(StoreFrontLogoutSuccessHandler.NAME)).and()
            .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(context.getBean(DefaultRememberMeServices.class)).and()
            .portMapper()
                .http(80).mapsTo(443)
                .http(8111).mapsTo(8112)
                .http(8080).mapsTo(8443).and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(defaultCheckoutAccessDeniedHandler()).and()
            .requestCache().requestCache(httpSessionRequestCache());
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultLoginCheckoutGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler", "loginCheckoutGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler"})
    protected AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultLoginCheckoutGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        final GUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new GUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(defaultLoginCheckoutAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        return guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultLoginCheckoutAuthenticationSuccessHandler", "loginCheckoutAuthenticationSuccessHandler"})
    protected AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultLoginCheckoutAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        final StoreFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new StoreFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/checkout");

        final Map<UiExperienceLevel, Boolean> forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel = new HashMap<UiExperienceLevel, Boolean>();
        forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel.put(UiExperienceLevel.MOBILE, Boolean.TRUE);
        forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel.put(UiExperienceLevel.NORMAL, Boolean.TRUE);

        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setForceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel(forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel);

        return storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultCheckoutAuthenticationFailureHandler", "checkoutAuthenticationFailureHandler"})
    protected AuthenticationFailureHandler defaultCheckoutAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        final LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler loginAuthenticationFailureHandler = new LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        loginAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/checkout/login?failed=auth");

        return loginAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultCheckoutAccessDeniedHandler", "checkoutAccessDeniedHandler"})
    protected AccessDeniedHandler defaultCheckoutAccessDeniedHandler() {
        final AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
        accessDeniedHandler.setErrorPage("/403");

        return accessDeniedHandler;
    }
}

@Order(2)
@Configuration
public static class DefaultStorefrontSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    public ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .headers().frameOptions().disable()
            .anonymous().principal("anonymous").authorities("ROLE_ANONYMOUS").and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()).and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/my-account*").hasRole("CUSTOMERGROUP")
                .antMatchers("/my-account/**").hasRole("CUSTOMERGROUP").and()
            .requiresChannel()
                .antMatchers("/login").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/register/**").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/signin/**").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/logout").requiresSecure()
                .antMatchers("/**").requiresInsecure().and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check").permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/my-account", false)
                .failureHandler(defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .successHandler(defaultLoginGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler()).and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(context.getBean(StoreFrontLogoutSuccessHandler.class)).and()              .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(context.getBean(DefaultRememberMeServices.class)).and()
            .portMapper()
                .http(80).mapsTo(443)
                .http(8111).mapsTo(8112)
                .http(8080).mapsTo(8443).and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(defaultAccessDeniedHandler()).and()
            .requestCache().requestCache(httpSessionRequestCache());

    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultLoginGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler", "loginGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler"})
    protected AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultLoginGUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        final GUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new GUIDAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(defaultLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler());

        return guidAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler", "loginAuthenticationSuccessHandler"})
    protected StoreFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        final StoreFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler = new StoreFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/my-account");
        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setUseReferer(true);
        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setRequestCache(httpSessionRequestCache());

        final Map<UiExperienceLevel, Boolean> forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel = new HashMap<UiExperienceLevel, Boolean>();
        forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel.put(UiExperienceLevel.MOBILE, Boolean.TRUE);
        forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel.put(UiExperienceLevel.NORMAL, Boolean.FALSE);

        storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler.setForceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel(forceDefaultTargetForUiExperienceLevel);

        return storeFrontAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler", "authenticationFailureHandler"})
    protected AuthenticationFailureHandler defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        final LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler loginAuthenticationFailureHandler = new LoginAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        loginAuthenticationFailureHandler.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?failed=auth");

        return loginAuthenticationFailureHandler;
    }

    @Bean(name = {"defaultAccessDeniedHandler", "accessDeniedHandler"})
    protected AccessDeniedHandler defaultAccessDeniedHandler() {
        final AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
        accessDeniedHandler.setErrorPage("/403");

        return accessDeniedHandler;
    }
}

@Bean(name = {"defaultAuthenticationManager", "authenticationManager"})
public AuthenticationManager defaultAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(opp).userDetailsService(context.getBean(PlatformUserDetailsService.class)).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder()).and().build();
}

// @formatter:on

@Bean(name = { "defaultRedirectStrategy", "redirectStrategy" })
protected DefaultRedirectStrategy defaultRedirectStrategy() {
    return new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
}

@Bean(name = { "httpSessionRequestCache", "requestCache" })
protected static HttpSessionRequestCache httpSessionRequestCache() {
    return new WebHttpSessionRequestCache();
}

/* Remember-me services */

@Bean(name = { "defaultRememberMeAuthenticationFilter", "rememberMeAuthenticationFilter" })
protected RememberMeAuthenticationFilter defaultRememberMeAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    return new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(defaultAuthenticationManager(), context.getBean(DefaultRememberMeServices.class));
}

@Bean(name = { "defaultRememberMeAuthenticationProvider", "rememberMeAuthenticationProvider" })
protected RememberMeAuthenticationProvider defaultRememberMeAuthenticationProvider() {
    return new RememberMeAuthenticationProvider("storefront");
    }
}
```

And then here's the REST web-config:

```
    @Order(value = 1)
public class RestServicesWebConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webCtx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    webCtx.register(RestServicesSecurityConfig.class);
    webCtx.register(RestServicesConfig.class);

    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    servletContext.addListener(new HttpSessionMutexListener());

    /* Spring REST Delegating Dispatcher Servlet */
    Servlet restDispatcherServlet = new RepositoryRestDispatcherServlet(webCtx);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic restDispatcherServletReg = servletContext.addServlet("restDispatcherServlet", restDispatcherServlet);
    restDispatcherServletReg.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    restDispatcherServletReg.addMapping("/rest/*");

    /* Character Encoding Filter */
    FilterRegistration charEncodingfilterReg = servletContext.addFilter("restCharacterEncodingFilter", CharacterEncodingFilter.class);
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    charEncodingfilterReg.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    charEncodingfilterReg.addMappingForServletNames(null, false, restDispatcherServletReg.getName());

    FilterRegistration corsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("corsFilter", CorsFilter.class);
    corsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

    /* Spring Security Delegating Filter */
    FilterRegistration springSecurityFilterChainReg = servletContext.getFilterRegistration("springSecurityFilterChain");
    springSecurityFilterChainReg.addMappingForServletNames(EnumSet.<DispatcherType>of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.ASYNC), false, restDispatcherServletReg.getName());
}
```

}

and the security config of the rest module:

```
    @Order(3)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class RestServicesSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private ObjectPostProcessor<Object> opp;

@Resource
public ApplicationContext context;

@Resource(name = PlatformUserDetailsService.NAME)
private PlatformUserDetailsService platformUserDetailsService;

// @formatter:off

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/rest/**")
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(defaultDigestAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/rest/**").requiresSecure().and()
        .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout").and()
        .addFilter(defaultDigestAuthenticationFilter());

}

// @formatter:on

/* Digest authentication */

@Bean(name = { "defaultDigestAuthenticationFilter", "digestFilter" })
protected DigestAuthenticationFilter defaultDigestAuthenticationFilter() {
    DigestAuthenticationFilter filter = new DigestAuthenticationFilter();
    filter.setUserDetailsService(context.getBean(PlatformUserDetailsService.class));
    filter.setAuthenticationEntryPoint(defaultDigestAuthenticationEntryPoint());

    return filter;
}

@Bean(name = { "defaultDigestAuthenticationEntryPoint", "digestEntryPoint" })
protected DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint defaultDigestAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new DigestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setKey("key");
    entryPoint.setRealmName("Contacts Realm via Digest Authentication");
    entryPoint.setNonceValiditySeconds(10);
    return entryPoint;
}

@Bean(name = { "defaultRestLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler", "restLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler" })
protected AuthenticationSuccessHandler defaultRestLoginAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
    return new RestAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
}

@Bean(name = {"defaultAuthenticationManager", "authenticationManager"})
public AuthenticationManager defaultAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(opp).userDetailsService(context.getBean(PlatformUserDetailsService.class)).passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder()).and().build();
}
```

}

Comment: Personally, I don't quite understand what the problem you are having is. I understand you are trying to break up your configuration in some way and that it is not working. I think some code samples for what is in your jar and what is in your war will likely help. Also you should clarify how you are specifying the springSecurityFilterChain For example are you using web.xml or AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer

Comment: Hi Rob, I added the code above. The springSecurityFilterChain I specify as a filter inside my WebApplicationInitializer. Currently in my rest web configuration I get the original filter:.getFilterRegistration("springSecurityFilterChain"); because if I try to add a new one it fails telling me that it was already added...

Comment: The RestServicesWebConfig is loading both RestServicesSecurityConfig and RestServicesConfig, so that i can just add the jar in my client's classpath and they can immediately get the /rest/* support + authentication. Unfortunately the authentication part doesn't work. It works, however, if I move the whole RestServicesSecurityConfig inside StorefrontSecurityConfig. But then I will lose the "drop it in your classpath and it will work" feature - I will always have to ask my clients to configure the security in their own config.

Comment: Also I noticed that if I add requiresChannel.requiresSecure() together with .basicAuth or digest auth it will end in a redirect loop when accessing the http channel.. maybe it's a bug.